# OnclickListener not working ....using recyclerview and below is code for my RecyclerAdapter and the two activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have tried using various listeners but it wont work.
The view is being produced well and everything else other than that listener is working just fine
I am a beginner in android and am doing the Jim Wilson Plural site course.
The other activity is not a problem because i have even tried using a Toast

**Adapter****strong text**

```
package com.example.plural;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.util.List;

public class NoteRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<NoteInfo> mNotes;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public NoteRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<NoteInfo> notes) {
        mContext = context;
        mNotes = notes;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.itemnotelist, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NoteInfo note = mNotes.get(position);
        holder.mTextCourse.setText(note.getCourse().getTitle());
        holder.mTextTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
        holder.mCurrentPosition=position;


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        public final TextView mTextCourse;
        public final TextView mTextTitle;
        public int mCurrentPosition;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextCourse = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textcourse);
            mTextTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.texttitle);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       Intent intent= new Intent(mContext ,NoteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.NOTE_POSITION,mCurrentPosition);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);




        /*int position = getLayoutPosition();
        Snackbar.make(v, "Click detected on item " + position,
                Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();*/




    }
});



        }
    }




}
```

**MainActivity code**

```
package com.example.plural;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.List;

public class NoteListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NoteRecyclerAdapter mNoteRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NoteListActivity.this, NoteActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        initializeDisplayContent();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mNoteRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void initializeDisplayContent() {

   /*    final ListView listNotes = findViewById(R.id.list_notes);
       List<NoteInfo> notes = DataManager.getInstance().getNotes();
       ArrayAdapter<NoteInfo> adapterNotes = new ArrayAdapter<>(NoteListActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);

       listNotes.setAdapter(adapterNotes);

       listNotes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NoteListActivity.this, NoteActivity.class);
//                NoteInfo note = (NoteInfo) listNotes.getItemAtPosition(position);
                intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.NOTE_POSITION, position);


                startActivity(intent);


            }
       });*/

        final RecyclerView recyclerNotes =findViewById(R.id.listnotes);
        final LinearLayoutManager notesLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerNotes.setLayoutManager(notesLayoutManager);

        List<NoteInfo> notes = DataManager.getInstance().getNotes();
        mNoteRecyclerAdapter = new NoteRecyclerAdapter(this, notes);
        recyclerNotes.setAdapter(mNoteRecyclerAdapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Click Listener on onBindViewHolder()

Like
`holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
{
public void onClick(){

```
          Intent intent= new Intent(mContext ,NoteActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.NOTE_POSITION,mCurrentPosition);
          startActivity(intent);
```

}
}`

Answer (score 0):

check this model for Adapter to add the click interface

```
public class FavouriteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouriteAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private OnItemClick onItemClick;
public FavouriteAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.customView,viewGroup,false);
    return new CustomViewHolder(view);
}

public void setOnItemClick(OnItemClick onItemClick){
    this.onItemClick=onItemClick;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {        customViewHolder.setClick(onItemClick,i);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 6;
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void setClick(final OnItemClick onItemClick, final int i) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                onItemClick.onClick(i);
            }
        });
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onItemClick.onDelete(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
public interface OnItemClick{
    public void onClick(int position);
    public void onDelete(int position);
}
```

}

and in main activity

```
mNoteRecyclerAdapter.setOnItemClick(new YourAdapter..OnItemClick() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ProviderDataItem providerDataItem) {
          
        }

        @Override
        public void onDelete(ProviderDataItem providerDataItem, int position) {
          
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[I just set back that attribute back to neutral and its now working....it was previously on TRUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JX6AZ.jpg)